# If..else use different input datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python beginner could you please help me to this?

***If variable is true I need to use A Dataset as input else have to use B dataset.***

How to write this please help me.

Comment: you can set a third variable that will be the data frame to use, which you can set to the the copy of A or B depending on if variable is true or not (i.e. `df = A.copy()` if variable is true etc).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question by adding some sample code? its easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "use" ?
I guess what you are looking for is `np.where(condition, do if true, do if false)` ?

Example from numpy doc:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
              [0, 2, 4],
              [0, 3, 6]])

np.where(a < 4, a, -1)

>>> array([[ 0,  1,  2],
           [ 0,  2, -1],
           [ 0,  3, -1]])
```

In your case it would be:

```
Something=np.where(Var, Action on dataset A, Action on dataset B)
```

If it's still not clear, please clarify terms like "variable" and "use as input" with a simple example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if it's still unclear @PythonDev

Answer (score 1):

You could create a third variable df and assign that to a copy of A or B and use that for the code:

```
if variable:
    df = A.copy()
else:
    df = B.copy()

##some code using df##
```

Alternatively, you could write a function for the code using the df, and have A or B as an input like this:

```
def df_function(df):
    ##some code using df##

if variable:
    df_function(A)
else:
    df_function(B)
```

Comment: thnq it helps :)

Comment: If this answers your question it would be good for you to accept it (the tick on the left)